# Add subclass to wildcard-typed generic collection in java

Tags: java, generics

This is legal:

```
List<? extends Animal> animals = getMonkeys();
...
List<Monkey> getMonkeys(){
    ...
}
```

The following results in a compiler error:

```
animals.add(new Donkey());
```

Why? How can I add a subtype legally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know which subclass the wildcard could be.  It could be a `List<Fish>` for all it knows.  To preserve type safety, the compiler must prevent a call to `add`, because one shouldn't be allowed to add a `Monkey` to what could be a `List<Fish>`.

```
List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Fish>();  // legal
animals.add(new Monkey());  // unsafe; compiler error
animals.add(new Donkey());  // also unsafe; compiler error
```

To prevent this, you need to eliminate the wildcard in your variable, so that the compiler knows the generic type parameter.  A `List<Animal>` or a `List<Monkey>` (or a `List<Donkey>` as the case may be) would allow you to call `add` with an argument of something other than `null`.  If you must call `getMonkeys()`, then you must use its return type of `List<Monkey>`.

```
List<Monkey> monkeys = getMonkeys();
monkeys.add(new Monkey());
```

Answer (score 3):

Just declare the list as `List<Animal>`. Any object which class extends from `Animal` will be able to be inserted there.

Use wildcard in a `List<? extends Foo>` when you're traversing the elements of the collection and want/need that the elements in the collection belong to a specific class. For example:

```
class Animal {
    public String getSpecie() {
        return "generic animal";
    }
}

class Donkey extends Animal {
    @Override
    public String getSpecie() {
        return "generic donkey";
    }
}

class Mokney extends Animal {
    @Override
    public String getSpecie() {
        return "generic monkey";
    }
}

//some method in an utility class...
//we are declaring that only List<Animal> or List<some class that extends animal> can be passed as argument
public void printSpecies(List<? extends Animal> animalList) {
    //we can be sure every element in animalList is an animal always
    for (Animal animal : animalList) {
        System.out.println(animal.getSpecie());
    }
}

//calling the method above...
List<Monkey> monkeyList = ...
printSpecies(monkeyList); //compiles and works
List<Donkey> donkeyList = ...
printSpecies(donkeyList); //compiles and works
List<String> stringList = ...
printSpecies(stringList); //doesn't compile
```

Comment: @achingfingers For breaking generic's inherent invariance.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this will also not compile. With the declaration `List<Animal> animals` the assignment `animals = getMonkeys()` will not compile.

Comment: @achingfingers Read the [Generics Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html), especially the chapter about [generics and subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html).